# Selectively sampling specific category in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to adapt Pandas `sample` command to selectively sample a specific category in a column while retaining all values from other categories? 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

e.g. in the dataframe below, I want to sample half of `Poor` Observed_Condition rows in the dataframe but retain all the Observed_Condition rows with Good or Excellent values:

```
Predicted   Observed_Condition
4.561074719 Excellent
3.114821134 Poor
5.47200407  Good
7.048857494 Excellent
5.318448093 Poor
3.81681577  Poor
5.640660645 Good
3.082072075 Good
3.249229815 Poor
4.492327775 Good
3.488655803 Poor
6.517144589 Good
```

Comment: Index the dataframe and then sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering by condition, add [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all non matched rows with filtering by inverted mask by `~`:

```
mask = df['Observed_Condition'] == 'Poor'

df = pd.concat([df[mask].sample(frac=0.5), df[~mask]]).sort_index()
print (df)
    Predicted Observed_Condition
0    4.561075          Excellent
2    5.472004               Good
3    7.048857          Excellent
4    5.318448               Poor
6    5.640661               Good
7    3.082072               Good
8    3.249230               Poor
9    4.492328               Good
11   6.517145               Good
```